# Copy logged values to starting at cell reference logged

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, logging, copy-paste

- I am trying to copy the 'values only' in the form over to a data sheet, with those values being copied onto the next empty cell available.
- I'm new to google sheets and am having some trouble making this work, if anyone could help that would be great.
- The values are not copying across the data range - only one column is copying.

code:

````
 
   var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var formSS    = ss.getSheetByName("NEW/ADD"); //Form Sheet
   var datasheet = ss.getSheetByName("reciepedata").getLastRow()+1;
 
 Logger.log(datasheet);
 
   //TITLE Values
   var values = [[formSS.getRange("F6").getValues()]];
 Logger.log(values);
 
   //TYPE Values
   var values = [[formSS.getRange("F7").getValue()]];
 Logger.log(values);
 
   //REF Values
   var values = [[formSS.getRange("F8").getValue()]];
 Logger.log(values);
 
   //SERVES Values
   var values = [[formSS.getRange("F9").getValue()]];
 Logger.log(values);
 
   //INGREDIENT Values
   var values = [[formSS.getRange("D12").getValues()],
                   [formSS.getRange("D13").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("D14").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("D15").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("D16").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("D17").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("D18").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("D19").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("D20").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("D21").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("D22").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("D23").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("D24").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("D25").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("D26").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("D27").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("D28").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("D29").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("D30").getValue()]];
   Logger.log(values);
 
   //AMOUNT Values
   var values = [[formSS.getRange("E12").getValues()],
                   [formSS.getRange("E13").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("E14").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("E15").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("E16").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("E17").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("E18").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("E19").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("E20").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("E21").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("E22").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("E23").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("E24").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("E25").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("E26").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("E27").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("E28").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("E29").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("E30").getValue()]];
     Logger.log(values);
 
   //MEASUREMENT Values
   var values = [[formSS.getRange("F12").getValues()],
                   [formSS.getRange("F13").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("F14").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("F15").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("F16").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("F17").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("F18").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("F19").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("F20").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("F21").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("F22").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("F23").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("F24").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("F25").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("F26").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("F27").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("F28").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("F29").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("F30").getValue()]];
 Logger.log(values);
 
     //SPECIFICATION Values
   var values = [[formSS.getRange("G12").getValues()],
                   [formSS.getRange("G13").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("G14").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("G15").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("G16").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("G17").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("G18").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("G19").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("G20").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("G21").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("G22").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("G23").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("G24").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("G25").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("G26").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("G27").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("G28").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("G29").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("G30").getValue()]];
 Logger.log(values);
 
     //METHOD Values
   var values = [[formSS.getRange("H12").getValues()],
                   [formSS.getRange("H13").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("H14").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("H15").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("H16").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("H17").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("H18").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("H19").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("H20").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("H21").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("H22").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("H23").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("H24").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("H25").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("H26").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("H27").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("H28").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("H29").getValue()],
                   [formSS.getRange("H30").getValue()]];
 Logger.log(values);
 
 datasheet.getRange(datasheet.getLastRow+1, 1, 19, 1).setValues(values);
 
 }```
````

Comment: Sorry just to be clear: the "datasheet" sets the cell to copy the values to.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

You will find it much faster to use setvalues() and getValues() whenever possible.  I used getDisplayValues since you said that you just wanted the value which I assumed that you meant to say that you probably have formulas on your sheet.

```
function myfunk101() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const ssh = ss.getSheetByName("NEW/ADD"); 
  const dsh = ss.getSheetByName("reciepedata");//This sheet name appears to be mispelled but I left it.  I'm guessing it should be "recipedata"
  const svs1 = ssh.getRange(7,1,4,1).getDisplayValues();
  const svs2 = ssh.geRange(12,4,19,4).getDisplayValues();
  dsh.getRange(dsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1,svs1.length,svs1[0].length).setValues(svs1);//this is one column wide
  dsh.getRange(dsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, svs2.length, svs2[0].length).setValues(svs2);//this is 4 wide
}
```